# Javascript Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get this function to work. I think the function is pretty self explanitory:

```
function FileExists(path){
    var result = false;

    $.ajax({
        url:    "http://mydomain.com/"+path,
        type:   "HEAD",
        success:
                function(){
                    result = true;
                }
    });

    return result;
}
```

I need the anonymous function that is called upon success of the ajax post to set the variable "result" that was defined inside the FileExists function to true so that I can return that value from the FileExists function. I think I need a closure for this but they confuse the hell out of me.

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax calls are by default asynchronous, you can either use a callback function:

```
$.ajax({
    url:    "http://mydomain.com/"+path,
    type:   "HEAD",
    success: function(){
        callback(true);
    }
});
```

Or make the call synchronously.

```
$.ajax({
    async:   false,
    url:    "http://mydomain.com/"+path,
...
```

Comment: There is almost no reason why one might want to use `async: false`; its mostly a crutch for lazy programmers, given it's effects.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a scoping issue, but rather because `$.ajax` is asynchronous, meaning that `FileExists` will `return` before `$.ajax` will complete. What you should be doing is to move all code that depends on `result` to inside the `success` callback.

Comment: But his question about closure brings up a good point, doesn't any assignment without `var` preceding it assign to global namespace? And if so, his `result=true` in the anon func assigns to global?

Comment: @philwinkle No, anon. functions are ran in the scope of the function that creates them. See a simple test case like: http://jsfiddle.net/txWLj/ The engine goes up through each scope looking for the variable until it reaches the global scope.